# How to send a proactive message to a specific channel and specific user using a Bot on BotFramework SDK v4

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

Send Notification message (adaptive card) to Microsoft Teams & Skype using a bot individually.

I have an approval workflow implemented, I'm trying to send approval notifications to these channels :
- Skype
- Teams

Depending on the user's notification preference that they can set from within the workflow applications notification settings.

I've created a pro-active bot to send an adaptive card to Teams along with a trigger. But I can't figure out how the bot can send a notification to the required channel.

My Code is as follows:

**ProActiveBot**

```
public class ProActiveBot : ActivityHandler
    {
        private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;
        public ProActiveBot(ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences)
        {
            _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
        }
        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            ConversationReference conversationReference = context.Activity.GetConversationReference();
            _conversationReferences.AddOrUpdate(conversationReference.User.Id, conversationReference, (key, newValue) => conversationReference);
            await context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Sent: {context.Activity.Text}"), cancellationToken);
        }
        protected override Task OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            ConversationReference conversationReference = context.Activity.GetConversationReference();
            _conversationReferences.AddOrUpdate(conversationReference.User.Id, conversationReference, (key, newValue) => conversationReference);
            return base.OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(context, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

**Notify Controller**

```
Route("api/notify")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TriggerController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
        private readonly string _appId;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;

        public TriggerController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, ICredentialProvider credentials, ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences)
        {
            _adapter = adapter;
            _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
            _appId = ((SimpleCredentialProvider)credentials).AppId;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            foreach (var conversationReference in _conversationReferences.Values)
            {
                await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken));
            }
            return new ContentResult()
            {
                Content = @"<html></body><h1>Sent</h1></body></html>",
                ContentType = "text/html",
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            };
        }



private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(new Attachment()
        {
            ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(".", "Cards", "notification.json"))),
        }), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me understand how i can choose a specific channel to send a notification to on BotFramework.

Comment: Just and FYI the Skype for Business channel is being dropped as of the end of this month for new bots, existing bots will work until October if this year. Source is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skypeforbusiness?view=azure-bot-service-4.0.

Comment: Oh okay.. Thanks for the update. But I still could use some pointers on how to proactively trigger a message to a specific channel and user.

Comment: @nadz Please have a look at [proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive) documentation to post message in channel.

Comment: @nadz Did that documentation help, or do you still need assistance?

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT Hi, thank you for the reply. I did manage to get it sorted! The lack of proper documentation for the new version makes things very hard. Nevertheless I do have a problem with the OnMembersAddedAsync method on my Bot; it doesn't give any member properties. Only the member Id and name.

Comment: It *should* include [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.channelaccount?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable). There [isnt't code that removes it](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/cf741724839ff5dae4b98bda98bc18d876d6a6d4/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ActivityHandler.cs#L99).  My guess is that Teams doesn't include it when it sends the MembersAdded event.